# How to cache data with pagination?

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I want to save data from db to cache and view chached data with pagination.
I try this code in model:

```
public function fetchAll(Select $select = null)
{       
    if (null === $select)
        $select = new Select ();

    $select->from ( $this->table );
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith ( $select );
    $resultSet->buffer ();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

And use this code for paginate and pass data to view:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator as paginatorIterator;

public function indexAction()
{
    $select = new Select ();

    $page = $this->params ()->fromRoute ( 'page' ) ? ( int ) $this->params ()->fromRoute ( 'page' ) : 1;
    $select->order ( 'my_table.'.$order_by . ' ' . $order_sort );

    $items = $myModel->fetchAll ( $select );
    $paginator = new Paginator ( new paginatorIterator ( $items ) );
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber ( $page );

    $view = new ViewModel (array (
        'page' => $page,
        'paginator' => $paginator,
    ) );

    $view->setTemplate ( 'path/to/phtml' );
    return $view;

}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 makes that easy as can be by providing a built in caching features for pagination. Here's the documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.paginator.advanced.html#caching-features

I was able to set it up in one of my projects in about 5 minutes.